# How to divide gridview in two equal parts

Tags: c#, asp.net, aspxgridview

I have a GridView

```
<asp:GridView ID="topDreamTeam" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" >
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="DREAMTEAM" DataField="teamName" />
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="topDTID" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("score") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" ForeColor="#333333" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#FFFBD6" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Navy" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FDF5AC" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4D0000" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FCF6C0" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#820000" />
</asp:GridView>
```

output after binding code

```
DREAMTEAM
-----------------
40    pavan11
30    raga11
19    Sidd11
11    Ramesh11
0     Murali11
0     madhu11
0     Sandeep11
0     Gani11
0     prachi
0     Ani11
```

I need it in following format:

```
1 pavan11 40         6 Sandeep11 0
2 raga11 30          7 Gani11 0
1-5 here             6-10 here
```

I am having hard time put counter in front names eg: 1 Pavan11 40

Answer (score 1):

I sugest to use repeater. i did the code bellow

```
<!-- Place this on the aspx file -->
    <div style="width: 217px; float: left;">
            <asp:Repeater ID="repeater1" runat="server">
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <ul style="list-style: none;">
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <li>
                        <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "cod")%>
                        -
                        <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "teamName") %>
                        -
                        <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "score") %></li>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    </ul>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
        </div>
        <div style="width: 217px; float: left;">
            <asp:Repeater ID="repeater2" runat="server">
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <ul style="list-style: none;">
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <li>
                        <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "cod")%>
                        -
                        <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "teamName") %>
                        -
                        <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "score") %></li>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    </ul>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
        </div>


//Place this on the code behind
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<person> lstPerson = new List<person>();
            lstPerson.Add(new person() {cod = lstPerson.Count + 1, teamName = "pavan11", score = "40" });
            lstPerson.Add(new person() {cod = lstPerson.Count + 1, teamName = "raga11", score = "30" });
            lstPerson.Add(new person() {cod = lstPerson.Count + 1, teamName = "Sidd11", score = "19" });
            lstPerson.Add(new person() {cod = lstPerson.Count + 1, teamName = "Ramesh11", score = "11" });
            lstPerson.Add(new person() {cod = lstPerson.Count + 1, teamName = "Murali11", score = "0" });
            lstPerson.Add(new person() {cod = lstPerson.Count + 1, teamName = "madhu11", score = "0" });
            lstPerson.Add(new person() {cod = lstPerson.Count + 1, teamName = "Sandeep11", score = "0" });
            lstPerson.Add(new person() {cod = lstPerson.Count + 1, teamName = "Gani11", score = "0" });
            lstPerson.Add(new person() {cod = lstPerson.Count + 1, teamName = "prachi", score = "0" });
            lstPerson.Add(new person() {cod = lstPerson.Count + 1, teamName = "Ani11", score = "0" });

            var part1 = lstPerson.Count / 2;

            repeater1.DataSource = lstPerson.Take(part1).ToList<person>();
            repeater1.DataBind();

            repeater2.DataSource = lstPerson.Skip(part1).ToList<person>();
            repeater2.DataBind();

        }


//The class created for the repeater binding
public class person
    {
        public Int32 cod { get; set; }
        public String teamName { get; set; }
        public String score { get; set; }
    }
```

I can't post the output image as i run on my local machine for not having reputation... Anyway, hope it helps!!!